# PrepareForSegue not executing

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I've had a very thorough look, I've browsed many similar SO threads but I still can't seem to figure out why PrepareForSegue is not executing when it should. I have implemented it in several other VCs and I can't see what's different this time.

PrepareForSegue func

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "viewProfile") {
            let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! ProfileController
            let x = sender as! UITapGestureRecognizer
            let location = x.locationInView(self.myBountiesTableView) as CGPoint
            let indexPath = self.myBountiesTableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(location) as NSIndexPath?
            let cell = self.myBountiesTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! BountyCellNew
            vc.userId = cell.bounty.bountyCreatedById!.description
        }
    }
```

The VC the prepareForSegue should be fired from: MyBountiesVC.

Things I have checked: The VC class is set to MyBountiesVC. The segue identifier is set to viewProfile.

The segue should be fired on click of a UIImageView which has a UITapGestureRecogniser attached to it. I have done a similar implementation in a different VC and it works fine.

Comment: Remove the if conditional and see if it gets called. Set breakpoints within the method.

Comment: Please post your tap gesture recognizer code as well.

Comment: @CaptJak yes I already did that

Comment: @CaptJak No it does not

Comment: @Abhinav there is no code. I placed the tap gesture on the the Image view. Which is exactly what I have done in another VC and it's working fine

Comment: In the Attributes Inspector for the UIImageView, did you check the box next to User Interaction Enabled?

Comment: @vacawama lol damn, that was it. Can't believe I missed that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you are calling `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` method in your tap gesture recognizer. I, personally, would prefer to add the image on UIButton and then connect the action handler of that button to the view controller I want to load on tap on image.

Comment: How do I ensure that when there is no tap gesture recognizer code? I do not have any in my other VC with the same setup.

Answer (score 0):

As vacawama made me realise, I had not ticked the 'User Interaction Enabled' box. Solved.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some code.

You need to have the Tap call the method to `performSegueWithIdentifier`, not just <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+click drag to the next VC.

Add

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:Selector("someMethod:"))
tap.delegate = self
yourImageView.addGesture(tap)
```

to your viewDidLoad. Make sure you've created the property for the imageView.

Then create the `someMethod` method:

```
func someMethod (sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil)
{
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("viewProfile", sender: self)
}
```

And then you're prepareForSegueMethod:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "viewProfile") {
            let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! ProfileController
            let x = sender as! UITapGestureRecognizer
            let location = x.locationInView(self.myBountiesTableView) as CGPoint
            let indexPath = self.myBountiesTableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(location) as NSIndexPath?
            let cell = self.myBountiesTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! BountyCellNew
            vc.userId = cell.bounty.bountyCreatedById!.description
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why should I do this when it's working without this code? What are the benefits of including this code?